# How did I just enabled my dropdown menu for tactile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, touch, jquery-events

I have a dropdown menu for desktop visitors with a HTML looking like the follwing:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="nav_header "><span class="main_menu_title">SERVICES</span>
    <ul class="nav_header_inner">
        <li><a href="/services/massage">Massage</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services/therapy">Therapy</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services/kindness">Kindness</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

By hovering over `li.nav_header`, the `ul.nav_header_inner` gets `visible`.

Obviously hovering doesn't work on tactile devices. And clicking on `li.nav_header` doesn't do anything either.

To enable this I started doing a js-function looking like the following:

```
function tappableMenu() {
  jQuery("li.nav_header").click(function() {

  });
}
```

and with only that code, the dropdown got visible by tapping on it.

**How is this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
$(function() {
      jQuery("li.nav_header").click(function() {
      $('.nav_header_inner').slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

Here is an [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3b5fe/)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not asking to solve the problem, in the description I state that is already solved. My question is: how did I solve it with an empty function?? I have no clue, but I'm curious.